# JavaFX Repeater

Tags: user-interface, timer, javafx

I want to have something like a TimerTask in JavaFX.

I have a order of Functions, this Functions should be repeated every 1/2 Second maybe every 1/4 Second.

This Functions have some effects for a GUI Component in JavaFX.

Can you give me an TimerTask (JavaFX) example ? I can not use Timer Task, becouse the Compiler said this:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Timer-0
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:237)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:398)
at javafx.scene.Parent$1.onProposedChange(Parent.java:245)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableObservableList.clear(VetoableObservableList.java:146)
at com.sun.javafx.charts.Legend$1.onChanged(Legend.java:55)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:134)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:48)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.callObservers(ObservableListWrapper.java:97)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.clear(ObservableListWrapper.java:184)
at javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart.updateLegend(AreaChart.java:420)
at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$2.onChanged(XYChart.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:134)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:48)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.callObservers(ObservableListWrapper.java:97)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.removeFromList(ObservableListWrapper.java:383)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.removeAll(ObservableListWrapper.java:271)
at de.sick.suit.framework.control.fx.HistogramChart.deleteData(HistogramChart.java:170)
at de.sick.suit.framework.samples.ImageHistogram.run(ImageHistogram.java:200)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Look at this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916640/javafx-not-on-fx-application-thread-when-using-timer/26916766#26916766

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// TIMER
        Timeline line = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.2), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0)
            {
                sek++;

                puls(imgHisto, startingArea);
                System.out.println(" Sek: " + sek);
            }
        }));
        line.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        line.play();
```

I handeld the Problem with a TimeLine. This works very fine for my example!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ScheduledService](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html).  The example from the javadoc:

> you may want to ping a server on a regular basis to see if there are any updates. Such as ScheduledService might be implemented like this:
>
> ```
> ScheduledService<Document> svc = new ScheduledService<>(Duration.seconds(1)) {
>     protected Task<Document> createTask() {
>         return new Task<Document>() {
>             protected Document call() {
>                 // Connect to a Server
>                 // Get the XML document
>                 // Parse it into a document
>                 return document;
>             }
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more Code, but as of now I think you are not updating the UI properly. If you are in another Thread (which you seem to be if you are using a Task), whenever you want to update the UI you need to use

```
Platform.runLater();
```

Your Stacktrace indicates this.

Answer (score 0):

You were updating GUI component outside the JavaFX application thread.
Try something like this

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
    //update GUI here
  }
});
```